Seeking advice on including company name change in Letter of Recommendation
I'm planning to apply to chemistry graduate school (for PhD) in the U.S., and one of my letters of recommendation will be from my manager at a small company. The company doesn't have individual employee emails, so my manager uses the general company email (e.g., xyz-company@gmail.com). Since there isn’t an official email (e.g., employee@company.com), my manager has agreed to sign the letter in ink and then submit it but the admissions committee may still want to verify the letter’s authenticity through the company’s website or by contacting them directly.
The issue is that the company is planning to change its name slightly in the next few months, and I'm concerned the admissions committee might not recognize the company name at the time they review my application, which could raise doubts about the letter’s legitimacy.
Would it be appropriate for me to ask my manager to include a line at the end of the letter mentioning the upcoming name change (e.g., "Please note that the company name will be changing from X to Y in [timeframe]")? Would this be considered acceptable?
Thanks!

Why wouldn't it be? I can't think of any reason why anyone would be offended by such a comment, deem it inappropriate or out of line.

This seems like something that probably ought to be in all communications that your company sends out in the next few months - anyone you deal with is going to be confused if they haven't been warned.

Yes, totally appropriate. For the most part, there is no special set of rules for letters of recommendation; anything that is generally reasonable for professional correspondence is reasonable here. In this case, a concise explanation of the weirdness is so reasonable that one would hope your manager would include it even without your suggestion. But certainly no harm in suggesting it. Good luck.
